# How to block subdomains containing a string with iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I already know how to block domains that contain a specified string

```
iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo bm --string "test" -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m string --algo bm --string "test" -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "test" -j DROP
```

and to save iptables configurations in
`/etc/iptables/rules.v[4(ipv4);6(ipv6)]`

Unfortunately, while this blocks websites which contain the string in their (toplevel) domain **this configuration doesn't seem to block websites, the subdomains of which contain the matching string** (so *speedtest.net* would be blocked, but not *https://search.brave.com/search?q=test*)

I would be open to other approaches as well, as long as they are low level *(aka not requiring non-standard software or GUI apps)* and are Linux compatible *(or even better yet cross-platform)*

Comment: See if this can answer the question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43817601

Comment: The answers provided in there would (from my understanding) only work in blocking an occurrence of both unless it is provided in different commands, which would be cluttered

Comment: aka because of the "/\/test" parameter it would only block domains, which have the specified subdomain. Still thanks for linking the question as it provides useful resources, that I haven't yet seen before

Comment: furthermore the command `iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo bm --string "/\/test" -j DROP` doesn't block subdomains containing the string,(as googling test still works)

Comment: I'm curious about what the expectation is here. It will probably block DNS requests and some responses but surely not much else.

Answer (score 0):

> --algo bm

It's broken since kernel 5.1 or so, doesn't work with current 6.2.15. Use `--algo kmp`.

https://github.com/ooni/probe/issues/1641
https://bugzilla.netfilter.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1390
https://marc.info/?l=netfilter-devel&m=168552032530976&w=2